# Хэширование bcrypt C++

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, хеширование, g++

Как реализовать хэширование в C++. Например:

```
 std::cout << "Type password";
 std::string text;
 std::cin >> text;
```

Как захэшировать переменную `string text`? Подскажите стандартные функции? Самые часто используемые!

Comment: Что именно вы понимаете под "захешировать переменную"? Если вы имеете в виду - получить хеш-значение типа, скажем, `unsigned int` для строки - то для этого есть **масса** способов. Вплоть до просто просуммировать все символы :) Или использовать стандартный способ: `std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
     size_t hash = hash_fn(s);`

Comment: @Harry В том и дело. Мне нужно получить, например, такой вывод:
    
`Type text: sometext(пользовательский ввод) \n
hash is df66477jjkkf994(напрмер)\n.` Используя стандартные функции, если такие есть.

Comment: Хэш функция принимает значение и возвращает обьект целочисленного типа,  но   так, чтобы по возможности значения  этого обьекта  не совпадали с возвращаемым значением другого хэшируемого обьекта... Вот и сами решите как написать такую функцию или пользуйтесь  уже написанными хэш функциями...

Comment: Видите ли... Вы, наверное, удивитесь, но понятия единственно верной хеш-функции нет. Более того, само значение можно рассматривать как частный случай - тождественной хеш-функции :) Какое хотя бы вы хотите получить значение? Его размер, например?

Comment: Алгоритмов хэширования огромное количество, и каждый из них выдаёт своё количество байт на выходе. Так что вам необходимо как минимум определиться с требованиями к хэш-функции и её выходным данным.

Comment: @Harry Добавил в вопрос дополнение

Comment: Если нужен именно хеш - т.е. значение, которое позволяет размещать значения в хеш-таблице - то надо использовать что-то небольшое, тут даже crc32 великоват... А если нужен дайджест - см. в сторону sha256, sha1, md5...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions